# Unit-testing responses using the Requests library

Tags: python, unit-testing, urllib2, python-requests

I'm in the process of switching from URLLib2 to Requests, but I'm not sure how best to duplicate my current unit-testing functionality: I install a custom [OpenerDirector](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.install_opener) instance containing the response content and HTTP code I want to process, which is very flexible. I know that libraries such [Mocker](http://labix.org/mocker) exist, but is there a best practice / method in wide use for Requests?

Comment: @MartijnPieters That answer a) hasn't been accepted, and b) I specifically noted that I was aware of the library in question, while asking whether there was a consensus and/or best practice.

Comment: It doesn't really matter that the other answer was not accepted. Your *question* is still covering the same ground. You could add a bounty to the other questions instead perhaps? The other answer did receive 6 upvotes and no competing answers, so perhaps that is already the consensus and best practice?